# Android kernel and init.rc

Tags: android, android-kernel

We built android kernel for wandboard. Now, we must add some files and change init.rc to start service for that files(driver for touchscreen). With the help of adb we pulled init.rc and edited, later pushed back. However, after reboot init.rc remains unchanged, so we cant start service for our driver.

How can we accomplish writing init.rc?

List of boot partition:

```
boot
```

As you can see, there is no initrd directory or file

With regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every boot the file system is copied from a static image.  I believe the image is ramdisk.  I do not know how to do this, but you would have to unpack the ramdisk, change the files therein, and then pack it back up into the correct format.